# matrix of linear map T where matrix required is the composition of T, k times

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

For the question below, I am having trouble writing out the matrix for $T^k$.  I am not sure how I could write the matrix for $T$   in this case.  What I believe is troubling me about this question is how $T$ is defined.  How should I interpret the composition of $T$ with itself $k$ times?

Thanks in advance

$P_3$ refers to the polynomial with degree up to $3$, and $p'$ refers to the first derivative of $p$

> Let $T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow P_3(\mathbb{R})$ be the operator 
>   $$T:p\rightarrow p'-p''+p'''$$
>
> Write the matrix for  $T^k=T\circ\cdot\cdot\cdot\circ T$
>
> (with $k$ factors)  $\forall k=1,2,...,$ using the standard basis of $P_3$

Comment: To write a matrix for $T$ (or $T^k$), you just need to know what $T$ does to basis vectors. What's the basis for $P_3$? What does $T$ do to it? What about $T^2$, $T^3$, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The vectors in the standard base (in the polynomial representation) are $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$.

Now we need to find the image of the elements under the operator: $$ 1 \rightarrow 0$$ $$ x \rightarrow 1$$ $$x^2\rightarrow -2+2x$$ $$x^3\rightarrow 6-6x+3x^2$$.

Now we can project those images on the base obtaining the matrix representation of the operator:
$$[T]= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    -2 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
    6 & -6 & 3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$.

Now you just need to raise this matrix to the $k$th power.